# NSData and UIImage

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, uiimage, nsdata

I am trying to load `UIImage` object from `NSData`, and the sample code was to `NSImage`, I guess they should be the same. But just now loading the image, I am wondering what's the best to troubleshoot the `UIImage` loading `NSData` issue.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

UIImage has an -`initWithData:` method. From the docs: "The data in the data parameter must be formatted to match the file format of one of the system’s supported image types."

Comment: Yes, that's what I am using. The NSData has address, while after call UIImaeg -initWithData:theData, the point become 0. I am not sure where to see the error message.

Answer (score 106):

I didn't try `UIImageJPEGRepresentation()` before, but `UIImagePNGRepresentation` works fine for me, and conversion between `NSData` and `UIImage` is dead simple:

```
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
UIImage *image=[UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

Answer (score 21):

Try this to convert an image to NSdata:

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
NSData *data1 = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img);
```

Answer (score 3):

theData should be a `NSData` object which already contains the data. You need to do the file loading/downloading to the `NSData` object before it is used. You can inspect it by using `NSLog` on theData and see if it contains the valid data.

Answer (score -1):

For safe execution of code, use if-let block with Data, as function UIImagePNGRepresentation returns, optional value.

```
if let img = UIImage(named: "Hello.png") {
    if let data:Data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img) {
       // Handle operations with data here...         
    }
}
```

> Note: **Data** is Swift 3 class. Use Data instead of NSData with
>   Swift 3

Generic image operations (like png & jpg both):

```
if let img = UIImage(named: "Hello.png") {
        if let data:Data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img) {
               handleOperationWithData(data: data)     
        } else if let data:Data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 1.0) {
               handleOperationWithData(data: data)     
        }
}

*******
func handleOperationWithData(data: Data) {
     // Handle operations with data here...
     if let image = UIImage(data: data) {
        // Use image...
     }
}
```

By using extension:

```
extension UIImage {

    var pngRepresentationData: Data? {
        return UIImagePNGRepresentation(img)
    }

    var jpegRepresentationData: Data? {
        return UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self, 1.0)
    }
}

*******
if let img = UIImage(named: "Hello.png") {
      if let data = img.pngRepresentationData {
              handleOperationWithData(data: data)     
      } else if let data = jpegRepresentationData {
              handleOperationWithData(data: data)     
     }
}

*******
func handleOperationWithData(data: Data) {
     // Handle operations with data here...
     if let image = UIImage(data: data) {
        // Use image...
     }
}
```