# Screen sharing in iOS app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, screensharing

I want share my application iPad screen with other devices which are running the same application.

More detail: My application is a meeting application. Now I want that those who are the participants of that particular meeting can my screen when I share my application screen.

Conclusion: I want to share my app screen with other devices which have running the same app, JUST like Skype screen share.

Comment: Hi, did you find any answer to this question. Is it possible to share screen on iOS devices?

Comment: I don't think it is possible, as the permissions for any iOS app restricted to the current app which is in the foreground. Once the app goes background the `UIApplication` reference don't process anything, as a result no screen imaging will work.

Comment: Hello, Have you found any solution? @shiva: It is understood in iOS that, we only can share screen of our app, we cant anything outside our app, but my question is it still possible to share screen limited to our own app only

Answer (score 8):

You will be needing a server for this. Its a long process. Briefing you with the overall details

- You get the information when users are loggedIn.
- User will try to send the image to the server first.
- Get the screenshots images continuously from the user screen.[follow this link](http://www.icodeblog.com/2009/07/27/1188/)
- convert the [image to NSData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257400/nsdata-and-uiimage).
- From server detect the other user(to whom screen is to be shared.) send the data to that user. And convert the NSData into UIImage and update the UI accordingly.
- Loop the process.

  // [for taking screen shot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200736/how-to-take-a-screenshot-programmatically)

  ```
   UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.window.bounds.size);
      [self.window.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
      UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
      UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
      NSData * data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
      [data writeToFile:@"foo.png" atomically:YES];
  ```

Comment: Wow, that's mighty expensive just for screen sharing!

Comment: @CodaFi Yup you can say that.:) You can wait [Skype API for iOS](http://devforum.skype.com/t5/Developer-Corner/What-about-IOS/td-p/6427). It might be free. :P

Comment: Hi HDDeveloper/Harsha,
I am an iOS senior developer, working currently on screen-sharing iOS app. I saw your answer here, sure it would help me.And would like to discuss with you on this. I am deliberately need your help, as its urgent for my development. Could you please share your email please. Please check my query here->stackoverflow.com/questions/20054509/… how can i proceed further? - -Getsy

Answer (score 0):

you can do this exchange the image stream`(Current screen image context / Captured current screen)` for both device vice-versa.
Means transfer current context of your screen to connected device and make this process like continues sending/receiving like live stream of data.

Screen sharing working you get idea from following links.

1) [Desktop sharing](http://computer.howstuffworks.com/how-desktop-sharing-works.htm)
2) [Remote access of device](http://computer.howstuffworks.com/vpn3.htm)